# Windows 8 Date and Time Sync Issues

Tags: windows-8, time, date-time

I have an Asrock Z77-EXTREME4-M motherboard and use Windows 8 retail. The system clock is always wrong on boot and it seems to be off by however long it was since last boot. I.e. if I turn the computer off all weekend, the time on boot will be Friday when I start it up on Monday, Windows Time Service will not resync because the time-difference is so great. My guess is the BIOS is not keeping time.

How do I resolve this problem? The motherboard is so new I'm wondering if it could really be a CMOS battery issue?

Thanks

Comment: You should check your jumpers and see what your manual says they should be set to. If your Reset-CMOS or similar jumper is turned on, then the BIOS will be reset every time you boot.

Comment: By any chance are you dual-booting with Mac OSX? This will solve your problem: http://prasys.info/2010/01/fixing-time-sync-issue-with-osxwindows/ hint: try the registry fix

Answer (score 1):

Try the following suggestions:

1. Replace the CMOS battery. It can be defective even if it new.
2. Check the motherboard manual and jumpers position.
3. Try a different OS and check whether the problem persists.
4. Reset the BIOS settings to default.
5. Remove and reinsert the CMOS battery.